# C# calling public fields from a public static class

Tags: c#, .net, static, instance

I'm just learning C# after using VBA for many years, I'm not a professional and this is something I do in my leisure. I'm looking to replicate the logic of using a public variable that can be accessed from a method and incremented by one each time when clicking button   cmdPublicVartest ,   Below is the code I have so far, but am getting the error
****An object reference is required for the non-static field**, method, or property,** in the publicvar class, it looks because it's a static class, however if I remove it from a static class, I would have  to call an instance of the class on the button cmdPublicVartest. Is there a way I can keep publicvar a static class, so I don't have to do an instance of the class on the button?

```
namespace testDB
{
    public partial class Database : Form
    {
        public string publictest = "public test";
        public int pUblicint = 0;


         public static void   PublicVar()
        {
             
            MessageBox.Show(publictest + pUblicint);
            pUblicint++;

        }
        private void cmdPublicVartest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            testDB.Database.PublicVar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `publicint` and `publictest` are instance variables and not accessible without an instance reference from the static context, there is no implied `this` here.

Comment: `publicvar` is a method, not class.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't "call" fields. You "access" them.

Comment: `cmdPublicVartest_Click` is already an instance method, so it can call other instance methods without issue, so you should just be able to remove `static` and `testDB.Database.`

Comment: In addition to comments and answers, the problem being in the class design, the question is: what are you trying to do? What is your goal? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env, data types & expected result, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), images or sketches of screens, user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your skills take a look at [C# Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) and [Learn C# from Microsoft](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/csharp) in additions to online tutorials and profesional books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access non-static fields from a static method because they belong to an instance of the class, and when calling a static method you do not have an instance.

You could either make the fields static like this

```
public partial class Database : Form
    {
        public static string publictest = "public test";
        public static int pUblicint = 0;


        public static void PublicVar()
        {

            MessageBox.Show(publictest + pUblicint);
            pUblicint++;

        }
        private void cmdPublicVartest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            testDB.Database.PublicVar();
        }
    }
```

Or make the method non-static like this

```
public partial class Database : Form
    {
        public string publictest = "public test";
        public int pUblicint = 0;


        public void PublicVar()
        {

            MessageBox.Show(publictest + pUblicint);
            pUblicint++;

        }
        private void cmdPublicVartest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PublicVar();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

While `PublicVar()` is static, the fields it references (`publictest`, `pUblicint`) are not. You have to make them static as well or make `PublicVar()` not-static.

Comment: thanks for your help, I thought your answer was very helpful

Answer (score -1):

Just revise your code to this:

```
namespace testDB
{
    public partial class Database : Form
    {
        public string publictest = "public test";
        public int pUblicint = 0;


        public void PublicVar()
        {
         
            MessageBox.Show(publictest + pUblicint);
            pUblicint++;

        }
        private void cmdPublicVartest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PublicVar();
        }
    }
}
```